# What is acceptable level of BTree index fragmentation in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I wonder at which point it makes sense to rebuild BTree index on relatively large tables (couple hundred GB).

To me anything above 30% or 40% appears to be a good candidate, but I saw some say even 70% is not too bad for Postgres.  I'm getting fragmentation from `pgstattuple.pgstatindex` function if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `leaf_fragmentation` might not be a good indication for anything, but I'll gladly learn from somebody who knows better. According to the code, it is the percentage of leaf pages where the following leaf page has a lower block number. This *may* be meaningful if you scan bigger parts of an index that is stored on spinning rust, but nothing much else.

For me, the important column is `avg_leaf_density`. If that is too low, your index is bloated and inefficient.

The question what values are OK is a difficult one. I'd say that anything over 30% is fine, but 20% is not terrible either.

If you are unsure whether to rebuild an index or not, ask yourself the following:

- If you observe the bloat over time, does it continuously increase? If yes, that is bad, and a `REINDEX` is probably necessary.
- If the bloat stays high, but does not increase, `REINDEX` once and observe

  - Does that improve the performance of your application?
  - Does the index get bloated again until it is as bloated as before?

  "No" to the second question would suggest to leave the index alone.

If you decide to `REINDEX`, explore if more aggressive autovacuum settings on the affected table can keep the bloat down.

Answer (score 1):

It Depends™. Fragmentation by itself isn't good or bad, it's just a property of the index. If all your queries scan the index for a unique value, they will read a handful of pages, at most, in any case, so it doesn't matter if the index is fragmented. If, on the other hand, you routinely scan wide ranges of pages, lots of empty pages would probably hurt. You'll need to look at the I/O statistics to decide what's acceptable.